# Force an onClick animation to fully complete before running again

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, queue

I have a slider which controls the position by increasing and decreasing the margin when clicking a button. If you click the button a second time before an animation has completed, it starts from wherever it was, resulting in incorrect positioning.
Say the first click should move it 100px, but you click it again before it's finished (say when it's moved 50px), the result is that it moves 150px instead of finishing the 100px move then doing another to get to 200px.

Here's my code;

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#toMove').animate({
        marginTop: topMargin
    }, 1000);
});
```

TopMargin is set as a var higher in the code.

I've come across stop() and queue() but I'm not sure if I'm using them correctly as I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
 $('#toMove').animate({
    marginTop: topMargin,
    complete: function() {
                $(this).css('margin-top','0px');
           }
 }, 1000);
});
```